# tkinter, pandas and python, how to do

Tags: python, pandas, tkinter

I have a data frame and I need a input where I put the characters in the first column and I need a output that it gives to me the character of the same row but different column.

Example:

I have 3 columns in the data frame, Names, Age and Gender, my input will be the Name and I need 2 outputs to know the Age and the Gender faster than look for it in excel. It would be possible?

I need help! im very new on this!

Comment: Something like this `df['Age'].where(df['Names'] == 'name').dropna()` ? If you want to run it as .exe with Tkinter gui just watch some tutorials on youtube, this channel has nice Tkinter playlist: https://www.youtube.com/channel/UC8butISFwT-Wl7EV0hUK0BQ

Comment: _"how to do"_ is a question for youtube, here we answer _"what went wrong"_.

Comment: @CoolCloud thanks for ur time and ur help